# Existence of solution

Tags: functions

How do I show existence of solution to some equation? I have an equation with continous functions, and three unknowns, and I just need to show that these three unknowns exist.

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Can you be more specific? How about posting the equation?

Comment: Since you don't specify any example.... just consider three perpendicular planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove the existence of a solution is if you can do the following:

Collect all the terms of your equation on the left side of the equality sign.
Show that the left side of the equation is a single continuous function
of the three unknowns.
If this function is $f(x,y,z),$ find two lists of values of the unknowns,
$(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2),$
such that $f(x_1,y_1,z_1)<0$ and $f(x_2,y_2,z_2)>0.$
Parameterize the line through $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$
by a single variable $t.$
Show that the values of the function $f$ along this line then are given by
$f(x,y,z) = g(t)$ where $(x,y,z)$ is any point along the line.
Use the continuity of $f$ to show that $g$ is continuous over at least the
interval that parameterizes the segment from
$(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2,z_2).$
Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to that interval of $g$
to show the existence of a $t_0$ such that $g(t_0)= 0.$
From that and the parameterization already defined,
show the existence of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
such that $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0.$

Most of this is fairly mechanical. The tricky part is finding 
values of the unknowns such that $f(x_1,y_1,z_1)<0$ and $f(x_2,y_2,z_2)>0.$
I believe there is no algorithm to do that in general.
That's why I wrote "*if you can* do the following" rather than simply
"do the following."

Comment: So I basically isolate one of my three variables, and then consider it a function of the two others, and if this function is continous, then existence is guaranteed?

Comment: It occurs to me I assumed all your functions are real-valued. If they are complex-valued then my answer doesn't work. The domain also has to include a path between some point where $f<0$ and a point where $f>0.$ I don't think you can use this answer at all unless you can find two points like that. Mere continuity is not enough, even if you eliminate a variable (or two variables).